# Using form array in form array in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to create a form builder in angular 8 .

i want to create a form builder . in this form builder i want to declear a input and for that input may be need to set validation . in this form `input` and `vlaidation` must be dynamic .

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynaimc-form-builder?file=angular.json)

i initialised this form :

```
  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      type: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      label: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      inputType: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      formName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      validations: this.formBuilder.group({
        name: [''],
        message: [''],
        validator: ['']
      })
    });
  }

initialFormBuilder(): void {
 this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  formItem: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
});
}

  alidationItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [''],
      message: [''],
      validator: ['']
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.formGroup.get('formItem') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }

  addValidation(): void {
    this.validationItems = this.formGroup.get('formItem').get('validations') as FormArray;
    this.validationItems.push(this.validationItem());
  }
```

and this is the html code :

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <div formArrayName="formItem" *ngFor="let item of formGroup.get('formItem').controls; let i = index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <mat-label id="add">Add New input</mat-label>
                <div class="from-field-container">
                    <div class="col-25">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
                            <mat-label>From Name</mat-label>
                            <input matInput placeholder="Form Name" formControlName="formName">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-25">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>Type Field</mat-label>
                            <mat-select formControlName="type">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of formType" [value]="item.type">
                                    {{item.type}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-25">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
                            <mat-label>Field Label</mat-label>
                            <input matInput placeholder="Field Label" formControlName="label">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-25">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>Input Type</mat-label>
                            <mat-select formControlName="inputType">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of inputType" [value]="item.type">
                                    {{item.type}}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-25">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
                            <mat-label>Field Name</mat-label>
                            <input matInput placeholder="Field Name" formControlName="name">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div formArrayName="validations" *ngFor="let validation of formGroup.get('formItem').get('validations').controls; let j = index">
                    <div [formGroupName]="j">
                        <div class="col-25">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
                                <mat-label>Validation Name</mat-label>
                                <input matInput placeholder="Validation Name" formControlName="name">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-25">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
                                <mat-label>Validation Message</mat-label>
                                <input matInput placeholder="Validation Message" formControlName="message">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-25">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
                                <mat-label>Validator</mat-label>
                                <input matInput placeholder="Validator" formControlName="validator">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

**Now when  I add this line `<div formArrayName="validations" *ngFor="let validation of formGroup.get('formItem').get('validations').controls; let j = index">`**

it shows me this error :

> ```
> <div formArrayName="validations" *ngFor="let validation of formGroup.get('formItem').get('validations').controls; let j = index">
> ```

What I need is when user clicks on the new validation button, it should add a new validation for him.

**What's the problem here ? How can I solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add array of formGroup to validation property then you have to use formArray

**Try this:**

**component.ts**

```
createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      type: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      label: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      inputType: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      formName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      validations: this.validationItems
    });
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div formArrayName="validations" *ngFor="let validation of item.get('validations').controls; let j = index">
        <div [formArrayName]="j">
          <div class="col-25">
            <label>Validation Name</label>
            <input placeholder="Validation Name" formControlName="name" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-25">
            <label>Validation Message</label>
            <input placeholder="Validation Message" formControlName="message" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-25">
            <label>Validator</label>
            <input placeholder="Validator" formControlName="validator" />
          </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqtv1t)

Comment: i need create dynamic validation form for fields . in your example i can not add dynamic

Comment: I have just modified your code only, I have not removed anything, What is your use case?

Comment: i want to create a form builder . in this form builder i want to declear a input and for that input may be need to set validation . in this `input form` and `vlaidation` all of them must be dynamic .

Comment: this is smaple .https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynaimc-form-builder?file=angular.json

Comment: You have to use FormArray instead of single formGroup, why you still using validations control as single formGroup?